# Emacs で 起動時に M-x コマンドを実行するには

Tags: emacs

Emacs の M-x コマンドを起動時に実行するように設定ファイル(.emacs)に書くにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

例えば、M-x speedbar として実行しているコマンドを起動時に実行するようにするには、設定ファイルにどう書けばいでしょうか？

ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loaddefs.el` には以下の様に定義されています。

**emacs/27.0.50/lisp/loaddefs.el**

```
(defalias 'speedbar 'speedbar-frame-mode)
(autoload 'speedbar-frame-mode "speedbar" ...
```

`speedbar-frame-mode` の定義は以下の通り。

**emacs/27.0.50/lisp/speedbar.el**

```
(defun speedbar-frame-mode (&optional arg)
  "Enable or disable speedbar.  Positive ARG means turn on, negative turn off.
A nil ARG means toggle. ...
```

なので、

```
(speedbar 1)
```

もしくは

```
(speedbar-frame-mode 1)
```

と記述する事になります。

Comment: ご助言通りに設定するとうまくいきました！
ありがとうございました！